# Why can't I do char c = 'A'; c.toLowerCase() and instead have to do Character.toLowerCase(c);

Tags: java, class, reference, wrapper, primitive

Why is it only done like

```
char c = 'A';
Character.toLowerCase(c);
```

and not..

```
char c = 'A';
c.toLowerCase();
```

I find this very confusing and don't know where I can find more information about why this happens or why it's necessary.

Comment: Because in Java a `char` is not an object, so you cannot call methods on it.

Comment: That's something only the designers of Java can answer.  There's something called "autoboxing", which came in in Java 5.  It means that there are circumstances where you can use a primitive value as if it were an object, and it gets converted automatically to an object.  Only the designers of Java can say why they didn't extend autoboxing to the case where you place a dot after a primitive value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

**`char` type is a primitive**, and primitives do not have methods.

Furthermore, **`char` is obsolete**. Use [**code point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead when working with individual characters.

```
Character.toString(
    Character.toLowerCase(    // Takes a code point integer number.
        "A".codePointAt( 0 )  // Annoying zero-based index numbering.
    )                         // Returns another code point integer number.
)                             // Returns a `String` containing a single character.
```

> a

## Primitive versus Object

You said:

> I find this very confusing

You need to learn the difference between the dual [type systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) in Java:

- primitive
- object

You said:

> where I can find more information

See the Java Tutorial provided by Oracle free of cost. See [*Primitive Data Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [*What is an Object?*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html).

And [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20primitive&t=osx&ia=web) for "java primitive".

### Only objects have methods

The `char` type is a primitive. So it has no methods. Only objects have methods.

The [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) class provides a `static` method [`toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char)) which takes a `char` primitive value as its argument.

You asked:

> why it's necessary

Primitives are not [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Primitives were originally included in Java to make porting of [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) code easier, an ability considered quite important back in those days.

## `char` is obsolete

You should know that the `char` type has been obsolete since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters — essentially broken.

### Code point

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

The code point for LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A is 65 decimal, 41 [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Get the code point of a character.

```
int codePoint = "A".codePointAt( 0 ) ;
```

Get a `String` containing the character for a code point.

```
String s = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

To get lowercase version of a character being represented by its code point.

```
int lowerCaseCodePoint = Character.toLowerCase( codePoint ) ;
String lowerCaseLetter = Character.toString( lowerCaseCodePoint ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "codePoint: " + codePoint ) ;
System.out.println( "s: " + s ) ;
System.out.println( "lowerCaseCodePoint: " + lowerCaseCodePoint ) ;
System.out.println( "lowerCaseLetter: " + lowerCaseLetter ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lkE3BA).

```
codePoint: 65
s: A
lowerCaseCodePoint: 97
lowerCaseLetter: a
```